# How to override Css over PrimeReact Css

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I have Primereact datatable like below

```
<DataTable value={prDetailList} showGridlines editMode="cell" style={{ height: '330px', overflow: 'scroll' }} tableStyle={{ minWidth: '50rem' }}>
                                {columns.map(({ field, header }) => {
                                    return <Column key={field} field={field} header={header} style={{}} editor={(options) => cellEditor(options)} onCellEditComplete={onCellEditComplete} />;
                                })}
                            </DataTable>
```

This has below css with primereact.css
[image]

To override this wrapper css I made css file like

```
.p-datatable > .p-datatable-wrapper {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

and I imported to my react js like below. But my css file not being overriden primereact one.

```
import './pr.module.scss';
```

How can I achieve that? I am using React with next.js. React version: 18.2.6 Next version: 13.4.3 PrimeReact version: 9.2.3